# How to access local and global variable with same name in C

Tags: c, scope, declaration, linkage

I had this assignment at school, wherein I had to find the output of the following C code, and also, to explain the output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i;
void fun1(void);
void fun2(void);
int main()
{
    fun1();
    fun2();
    return 0;
}

void fun1(){
    i=20;
    printf("%d\t",i);
}

void fun2(){
    int i=50;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

The output is 20   50
Because in fun1() the Global Variable 'i' is assigned to 20 and printed. And in fun2() the variable 'i' is a Local Variable, which is declared and initialized to 50, which is then printed.

I have this following question out of curiosity, how do I use the global variable 'i', in fun2()?
A simple solution would be to simply change the name and avoid the whole thing. But my curiosity is due to Java, where there is a keyword "this" to access class variable instead of a local variable.

so is there any way to do that in C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cheat and create a pointer to the global `i` before declaring the local `i`:

```
void fun2( void )
{
  int *ip = &i; // get address of global i
  int i = 50;   // local i ”shadows" global i
 
  printf( "local i = %d, global i = %d\n", i, *ip );
}
```

**EDIT**

Seeing as this answer got accepted, I must emphasize that you should **never** write code like this.  This is a band-aid around poor programming practice.

Avoid globals where possible, and where not possible use a naming convention that *clearly* marks them as global and is unlikely to be shadowed (such as prefixing with a `g_` or something similar).

I can't tell you how many hours I've wasted chasing down issues that were due to a naming collision like this.

Answer (score 5):

The only way is to hide the declaration of the local variable in a code block.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 10;

void fun2( void )
{
    int i = 20;
    printf("local i = %d\n",i);

    {
        extern int i;
        printf( "global i = %d\n",i);
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    fun2();
}
```

The program output is

```
local i = 20
global i = 10
```

Comment: If I see this kind of code in the program I will seriosly consider need of the programmer replacement

Comment: @P__J__ why do you say so?

Comment: Why does this work with the `extern` keyword?

Comment: @user129393192 The keyword extern means that the declaration refers to a variable with external or internal linkage.

Comment: Right. However, I thought the usage of that was across module boundaries (different `.c` files using the same global). How does it work here?

Comment: @user129393192 In this case the compiler decides that the block scope variable has (refers a variable with) external linkage and the linker finds such a variable with external linkage.

Comment: Got it, so it's a link-time fix, not compile-time?

Comment: @user129393192 Here the file scope variable i is hidden within the function by the local variable int i = 20;. So in this declaration extern int i; the compiler considers the variable i as it refers to a variable with external linkage. And such a variable is the variable i declared in the file scope.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to access a global parameter inside a function that has a local variable with the same name. It is usually bad practice to create such local variables in C though, as you saw, it is not prohibited.
In C++ you can solve it using namespaces but there is no equivalent in C.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to pass parameters to the function

```
void fun2(int fromExternalWorld){
    int i=50;
    printf("%d ",fromExternalWorld);
    printf("%d\n",i);
}

int main(void)
{
    fun2(i);
}
```

Otherwise is not possible to have two symbols with same name visible in the same scope.